# Gradle Android library build but not resolve symbols

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am doing an android-library using Gradle and its build successfully, but when I open some class that uses this dependency not resolve sysmbols. Why?

In my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

    //myDependency
    compile project(':myDependency')

}
```

Thanks.

Ps. My dependency is a pure Java project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio

Comment: Did you also add this dependency to your settings.gradle so Gradle knows about the location if your other project?